# How to get environment variables from pre action in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, schema

I need to set an environment variable value, e.g changing the value "8" of ENV_VAR in this image to "9" -

[image]

Using a script in the pre action of the scheme.

[image]

Is there any way to it?